# DIV above java applet

Tags: html, css, applet

I can't for the life of me figure out what I can do to get it to render as intended in IE or Chrome when the java applet is turned on.

The `currencChoiceDisplay` div should load as an overlay on top of the java applet but for some reason half of it gets cut off. Got a JSFiddle example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SN6Je/5/

Compare the difference in firefox and ie and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from div `#currencChoiceDisplay`. [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SN6Je/19/)